# python dictionary to create new data frame column

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I created a dictionary consisting of unique values from two columns in two separate files.  These two columns have equivalent values that are formatted differently and therefore will not merge correctly.

dataframe A:

```
A  B
1  dfg 
2  srg
3  sgf
4  sfh
3  srg
6  srg
1  sfg

d={1: 1.102832,
   2: 2.102832,
   3: 3.102832,
   4: 4.102832,
   5: 5.102832,
   6: 6.102832,
   7: 7.102832}
```

Final product should look like this:

```
A  B     C
1  dfg  1.102832
2  srg  2.102832
3  sgf  3.102832
4  sfh  4.102832
3  srg  3.102832
6  srg  6.102832
1  sfg  1.102832
```

I attempted to use pandas.Series.map as follows:

```
s["C"]=s["A"].map(dictionary)
```

Unfortunately my result looks like this:

```
A  B     C
1  dfg  NaN
2  srg  NaN
3  sgf  NaN
4  sfh  NaN
3  srg  NaN
6  srg  NaN
1  sfg  NaN
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible that the types of `s["A"]` and `d.keys()` don't match?

Comment: i printed the types and s["A"] reads: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> whereas d.keys() reads <type 'list'>.  How would I change them so they match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    A.ix[A['A']==key,'C'] = value
```

Assuming your first dataframe is called 'A' en your dictionary is called 'd'

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In theory what you tried should work. However, you have to pay careful attention to the types of the values in `s['A']` and the keys in `d` lest they do not compare equally. For example, if `s['A']` contains strings, while `d.keys()` contains ints, then

```
import pandas as pd
d = {1: 1.102832,
     2: 2.102832,
     3: 3.102832,
     4: 4.102832,
     5: 5.102832,
     6: 6.102832,
     7: 7.102832}

s = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':'1 2 3 4 3 6 1'.split(),
    'B':'dfg srg sgf sfh srg srg sfg'.split()})

s['C'] = s['A'].map(d)
print(s)
```

yields

```
   A    B   C
0  1  dfg NaN
1  2  srg NaN
2  3  sgf NaN
3  4  sfh NaN
4  3  srg NaN
5  6  srg NaN
6  1  sfg NaN
```

whereas if you convert `s['A']` to numerical values:

```
s['A'] = pd.to_numeric(s['A'], errors='coerce')
s['C'] = s['A'].map(d)
print(s)
```

then you get the desired result:

```
   A    B         C
0  1  dfg  1.102832
1  2  srg  2.102832
2  3  sgf  3.102832
3  4  sfh  4.102832
4  3  srg  3.102832
5  6  srg  6.102832
6  1  sfg  1.102832
```

Comment: This sounds like it will solve my problem but my C column is a little more complicated than I let on.  The values are variations of "lsl0807b.201302" and therefore cannot be converted to integers.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of values you wish to have in `C`. What's important is that values in `s['A']` (whatever they may be) compare equally with *keys* in `d`.